# Como convertir un string en byteArray en kotlin

Tags: java, android, array, kotlin

Actualmente ocupo este metodo para convertir a byteArray un string

```
 fun stringToByteArray(s: String): ByteArray? {
    val len = s.length
    if (len % 2 != 0) return null
    val data = ByteArray(len / 2)
    var i = 0
    while (i < len) {
        data[i / 2] =
            ((Character.digit(s[i], 16) shl 4) + Character.digit(s[i + 1], 16)).toByte()
        i += 2
    }
    return data
}
```

mi pregunta es si existe algun metodo mas simple para llegar al mismo resultado, buscando en la web encontre que se puede con esto

```
val byteArray = key.toByteArray()
```

pero por alguna razon me dan resultados diferentes, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

**Lo correcto es usar el método [toByteArray()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-byte-array.html) Que por default usa una codificación `UTF_8`**:

```
val valor = "Hola Emmanuel"
val bytes = valor.toByteArray()
```

puedes comprobar que es un `Byte Array` mediante `contentToString()` , ejemplo:

```
 val valor = "Hola Emmanuel"
 val bytes = valor.toByteArray()
 System.out.println(bytes.contentToString())
```

salida:

```
[72, 111, 108, 97, 32, 69, 109, 109, 97, 110, 117, 101, 108]
```

---

en cambio si usas el método que describes en tu pregunta no se obtiene un array, incluso posiblemente obtendrás un valor `null` ya que puede entrar en esta evaluación:

```
if (len % 2 != 0) return null
```

Comment: con el metodo que utilizo obtengo un array (en caso de no caer en esta validacion: if (len % 2 != 0) return null) el problema es que obtengo diferentes resultados
stringToByteArray me da un resultado y toByteArray() me da otro, el problema es que para decodificar la información que necesito solo lo puedo hacer con este metodo (stringToByteArray) ya que el otro metodo me dice que no puede decodificarlo.

Mi duda va más a conocer una manera de reducir el método que funciona (stringToByteArray ).